# Trouble with logic in this conditional statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I need to write this code so that the alert message doesn't display when the earth element is vertically aligned with the sun element, but rather when the earth element has the same horizontal and vertical coordinates.

I've tried using  both the `.position()` and `.offset()` methods, didn't work. You would think using same left positions AND top positions would do the trick, but the alert message pops up when the left position conditional statement is met.

Im having trouble properly writing the conditional statement.

```
var positionplanet = $("#Earth").position();
var positionsun = $("#Sun").position();

if (
    Math.round(positionplanet.left) == Math.round(positionsun.left) &&
    Math.round(positionplanet.top) == Math.round(positionplanet.top)
) {
    alert("planet and sun are on the same spot");
}
```

Comment: What you posted looks fine to me. *edit* oh wait, you're probably having `NaN` issues.

Comment: Are you sure this code same with what you run?

Comment: If you already fix your code in your question - what is you question then?

Comment: I didn't change anything to your code, except indentation and some other minor layout issues. I did NOT change any part of the code itself. According to the edit history, no changes (besides improvements of indentation) were made to the actual code by anyone else either, meaning your code already worked when you posted the question!

Comment: For future: no reason to fix question code to lost all conversation. Just accept correct answer and users reading this page will be able to see issue and solution.

Comment: @JohnSlegers, there is time gap to changes will not to create separate changeset in the history.

Comment: @vp_arth : According to the edit history, no changes were made to the actual code by anyone (except minor changes to the indentation)

Comment: Sure vp_art, I edited it because I didn't think that was the problem, but it was. I also didn't think anyone would have read the comment before the edit fast enough. It created a big confusion in a matter of seconds.

Comment: @Zhyohzhy : I just reverted your change back to include the error, because your question makes no sense otherwise. The proper thing to do, would be to accept Liam C's answer.

Comment: And now someone edited my edited question. I will take heed next time to never edit my question again!

Comment: @JohnSlegers Typo error questions should be closed anyway :)

Comment: @Zhyohzhy : There's nothing wrong with editing your own question, as long as it actually improves the question. By removing the error, your question no longer made sense... which is the only reason why I undid your change. Please don't feel discouraged to edit your questions in the future because of this!

Comment: @JohnSlegers Okay. Fair enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

positionplanet.top is used twice in your 2nd condition in the if statement. Change to:

```
var positionplanet = $("#Earth").position();
var positionsun = $("#Sun").position();

if    (Math.round(positionplanet.left) == Math.round(positionsun.left) 
    && Math.round(positionplanet.top) == Math.round(positionsun.top))
    { alert("planet and sun are on the same spot");}
```

Comment: Where are you seeing this?

Comment: I did! Such a stupid mistake of mine. Thank you

Comment: The question was edited - previously `positionplanet.top` was used twice in the if statement. No problem, easy mistake to make!

Comment: It wasn't according to the edit history?

Comment: I'm not seeing this in the edit history!

Comment: well, it was. Hence, the user was able to resolve his problem with this!

Comment: Anyway, I just upvoted you.